# Programatically detecting open HTTP requests on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there any way on Chrome (Chrome only) to detect how many requests are still open (within my page sandbox)?
Request examples:
xhr, documents, images, scripts, fonts, etc.

Using Javascript preferably.

And It's ok if it is a experimental feature it is to be run on localhost I just want to do some tests.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this in javascript?

Comment: @johntrandall not really

Answer (score 0):

Press: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> and you will see developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to programmatically detect network requests. This break the same origin policy and be a huge security flaw!

Using the Chrome DevTools (Press <kbd>F12</kbd> OR <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open them), you can view a timeline of all HTTP requests, as well as painting, scripting, etc.

1. Open DevTools (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Click the "Timeline" tab
3. At the bottom of the window, uncheck Scripting, Rendering, and Painting.
4. Hit the "Record" button (bottom left, the round icon)
5. Refresh you page as you normally would. The events will show on the timeline.

Comment: at the time I downvoted both answers because the question states "using javascript"

Comment: @fmsf I added a note about it not being possible.